# Get current TFS connection in a Visual Studio addin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-addins

I'm working on a Visual Studio 2010 add-in, and I'm trying to figure out how to determine the currently connected TFS server.  I'm guessing I need to use DTE, but I'm having a brain cramp figuring out where to get the info.

Comment: It looks like you're actually writing a package, not an add-in. Yes?

Comment: I thought a package as a collection of addins?  this is the first extension activities I've done with 2010, so I may be a little confused.

Comment: any solution for get TFS Connection in Addin ?

Comment: Thanks bro, would have taken me forever to find this

Comment: Thank you very much! Saved me a lot of hours.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo`  method, in result you have an object and access `ServerUri property`

See [this documentation on MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workstation.getlocalworkspaceinfo(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Robaticus originally edited the question with the solution. Converted it to a Community Wiki answer:

Actually, I may have found the answer, which I culled from a couple places.

```
var dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;

TeamFoundationServerExt ext = dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt") as TeamFoundationServerExt;

TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(ext.ActiveProjectContext.DomainUri);
VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

var changes = vcs.GetPendingChanges(null);
```